# How to keep Jquery function from overwriting one input field with onclick write to second input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with two input fields and a tag cloud.

I want the user to put focus in the first input, then click a tag thus triggering a jquery function that puts the clicked-on tag in the first input. Then the user  focuses the second input, clicks a tag triggering a similiar jquery function to put the second tag in the second input field.

My code works to put the first tag in the first input, but when the second tag is clicked, that clicked-on tag is put into both input fields.

I suspect I need help with $(this).html or binding.  It is clear to me that the $('a').click function is happening twice with the latest value of $(this).html().

How do I isolate the two functions so the first tag is written to the first input, and the second tag is written to the second input only?

Here's how I have written my html and jquery:

The form:

```
 <div id="content"> 
      <h3 class="replaceTag">Replace A Tag</h3>
    <p class="showToReplace">Replace 
          <input class="inputToReplace" type="text" name="" value=""> 
          With 
           <input class="inputWithReplace" type="text" name="" value=""> 
           <input type="button" name="" value="Go">
     </p>
```

The structure of the tag cloud, only showing "A" for brevity.

```
 <div id="tagReference">  
     <div class="tagWindow">

         <h4 class="alphaLetter">A</h4>

             <div id="alphachunk">
                 <a class="_tag_suggestion">access, </a>
                 <a class="_tag_suggestion">accessibility,</a>
                 <a class="_tag_suggestion">accountant, </a>
                <a class="_tag_suggestion">acoustical,</a>

             </div>

         <h4 class="alphaLetter>B</h4>
              <div id="alphachunk">
                  <!--and so on for the alphabet-->
              </div>
      </div> 
  </div>
```

This happens for each letter of the alphabet that a tag exists for.

Here is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inputToReplace').focus(function(){ 
     $("a").click(function(){  
         $('.inputToReplace').val($(this).html());
     });
    });

 $('.inputWithReplace').focus(function(){ 
        $("a").click(function(){  
         $('.inputWithReplace').val($(this).html()); 
             });  
  });
 });
```

Now, a lovely screen shot.
[alt text http://www.kevtrout.com/stackoverflowimages/editTagsScrn.png](http://www.kevtrout.com/stackoverflowimages/editTagsScrn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery allows you to bind multiple click event handlers. You will need to unbind the previous click event handler using `.unbind` before adding the second one (or both will fire, as you experienced):

```
$("a").unbind("click");
```

So your code could read:

```
$('.inputWithReplace').focus(function(){ 
    $("a").unbind("click").click(function(){  
     $('.inputWithReplace').val($(this).html()); 
         });  
});
```

Comment: 20 minutes to write the stupid question, 1 minute to get the answer.  I love you stackoverflow.  Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:text').focus(function(e){ 
      tagSelector(e.target);
  });
});

function tagSelector(elem) {
  $("a").unbind('click').click(function(e){  
    $(elem).val($(e.target).text()); 
  });  
}
```

You might need to use a more specific selector for the inputs, I'll leave that as an exercise for you to decide :)

**EDIT:**

or even this

```
$(function(){
  $('input:text').focus(tagSelector);
});

function tagSelector(e) {
  $("a").unbind('click').click(function(){  
    $(e.target).val($(this).text()); 
  });  
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the anchor has a class I use as a selector. I deleted it to keep the example clear.  Same with the names on the inputs.